# Python encryption scheme that supports multiple decryption keys

Tags: python, security, encryption

Is there a python library that supports (symmetric) encryption of data with the possibility of using multiple decryption keys.

I have (sensitive) user data that must be stored encrypted in a database, but it must be possible for multiple 3rd parties to access the data without giving them all the same secret.

This could be implemented by generating a random key K, encrypt the original data D to get D_K. Then I encrypting K with as many access keys (ak_1 to ak_n) as needed, store them for later use and destroy K. Whenever a 3rd party tries to access D the submit ak_i and I use it to decrypt K and us it to decrypt D_K to get D.

However, it would be nice to have a implemented since a) I don't like to reinvent the wheel and b) this is security and you probably won't get it 100% right.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the confusion and issues surrounding export controls of hard encryption, there's not a lot of 3rd party libraries that directly provide this sort of higher-level explicit encryption scheme.

For the most part you're going to have to wrap the toolset of something like [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) with your own key logic.  Seeing as it's crypto we're talking about, however, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out [the other libraries for lower-level hard encryption tools in Python.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations#Python)

Comment: Don't your first and second paragraphs contradict each other?

Comment: Edited to try and make this a little more clear.  My meaning is that while there are 3rd party libraries that support hard encryption, none that I am aware of directly implement the kind of symmetric system the OP asked for.